# why do people call interfaces with constructors when there is none in the contract?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20

I'm just looking at some code to see common design patterns but this one really doesn't make sense to me:

```
import "./zeppelin/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(projectAddress, _tokenAmount)
```

how is tokenAddress being injected into an interface here?
It's not a class, and the underlying erc20 has no constructor either.

Answer (score 3):

With `IERC20(tokenAddress)`, you are **casting** `tokenAddress` to an `IERC20` instance.

This act is purely for compilation, and it has no runtime implications.

It merely allows you to call `IERC20` functions on the `tokenAddress` address.

In order to execute the constructor of `IERC20`, you'd need to call `new IERC20(tokenAddress)`.

This would not compile, because you cannot instantiate an interface (nor an abstract contract).

---

With regards to:

> The underlying erc20 has no constructor

This is plain wrong, because every contract has a constructor.

When no constructor is explicitly implemented, the default (empty) constructor is viable.